# javascript counter not displaying least number of doubles

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get a counter to register the least number of rolls it took to get a double and then when they play the 'game' again if they got an even lower number of doubles it replaces the first answer with the newer one.

```
 count=0, doubles=0, lowest=10000000;
  function Roll()
 // Assumes: die images are in http://dave-reed.com/book/Images
 // Results: displays a randomly selected image of a 6-sided die
 {
   var roll1, roll2;

   roll1 = RandomInt(1, 6);
   roll2 = RandomInt(1, 6);
   document.getElementById('die1').src = 
         "http://dave-reed.com/book/Images/die" + roll1 + ".gif";
   document.getElementById('die2').src = 
         "http://dave-reed.com/book/Images/die" + roll2 + ".gif";
   count += 1;
   if (roll1==roll2) {
       doubles += 1;
   }
   if (doubles==3) {
       alert("You got three pairs of doubles!!! It only took you " +count+ " rolls to get it! Now, go directly to jail, do not pass go, and do not collect $200");
       doubles=0;
       count=0;

   }
   if (doubles==3 && lowest>count){
           lowest=count
           document.getElementById('lowestLine').innerHTML = count;
   }
   document.getElementById('countLine').innerHTML = count;
   document.getElementById('doublesLine').innerHTML = doubles;

 }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you're missing 'var' in front of the count property, etc. Either way, what does your console say?

Comment: @Jonast92 they are global variables, the code worked before i added the if(doubles && greater than) statement and the console says nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `doubles` to 0 once it becomes 3 and then you check if `doubles` equals 3 which is never true.

It looks like you should put

```
if (lowest > count) {
   lowest = count
   document.getElementById('lowestLine').innerHTML = count;
}
```

inside first `doubles === 3` check, but before you setting globals to `0`.

Like this:

```
if (doubles === 3) {
    alert("You got three pairs of doubles!!! It only took you " +count+ " rolls to get it! Now, go directly to jail, do not pass go, and do not collect $200");
    if (lowest > count){
       lowest = count
       document.getElementById('lowestLine').innerHTML = count;
    }
    doubles = 0;
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! i thought I tried all my options but I must've missed one